# Why I have data for a month and it does not appear described on the axis?

Tags: powerbi, linechart

I would like to know why I have data for July and in the xx axis only appears August and September?

It's been happening since the new update.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because your axis type is `Continuous` and in this case it doesn't draw all possible values (which will looks bad). If you set axis type to be `Categorical`, every value will get it's own label. See [Customize X-Axis and Y-Axis properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-customize-x-axis-and-y-axis#considerations-and-troubleshooting) article.